# How to join 3 open cv IplImages into one?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

So I have code like:

```
    IplImage* redchannel = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(destination), 8, 1);
                    IplImage* greenchannel = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(destination), 8, 1);
                    IplImage* bluechannel = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(destination), 8, 1);
cvSplit(source, bluechannel, greenchannel, redchannel, NULL);
// code...
//now I need to join them back
```

How to join  bluechannel, greenchannel and redchannel back into some    IplImage* destination ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

void cvMerge(const CvArr* src0, const CvArr* src1, const CvArr* src2, const CvArr* src3, CvArr* dst);

[Here is the documentation.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsplit#merge)

**Edit:**

From the documentation:
You will have to call:

```
cvMerge(bluechannel, greenchannel, redchannel, NULL, target);
```

Assuming that your target image also has only 3 channels.

Comment: hm.. how to get 4 images if I have 3?

Comment: how to create such target? why IplImage* destination = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); works incorrectly?

Comment: "works incorrectly" is very unspecific, what do you mean by that?